# How do I toggle value and class of a button on button click

Tags: jquery

I have 4 buttons and I want only one button to be obviously selected and the other 3 to be obviously not selected.

```
<td width=10%><button class="stuck unstuck" name="doR1" id="doR1"  onclick="doR('1');">AP Enquiry</button></td>
<td width=10%><button class="stuck unstuck" name="doR2" id="doR2" onclick="doR('2');">HM Enquiry</button></td>
<td width=10%><button class="stuck unstuck" name="doR3" id="doR3" onclick="doR('3');">Ac/Rj Pgm</button></td>
<td width=10%><button class="stuck unstuck" name="doR4" id="doR4" onclick="doR('4');">Property Enq</button></td>
```

I can change the class ok using

```
$(".stuck").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  $(this).toggleClass('unstuck');
});
```

but this isn't enough as I want only the class of the latest button clicked to be changed, this code will allow me to change the class of all the buttons. I also want to change the value of only the latest selected. The particualr value doesn't matter as long as it toggles between 2 values, with the selected button being one value and all the other buttons being the other value.

Jbap

Comment: I edited the question for you to fix the formatting

Comment: Thanks Rory, much appreciated

Comment: Also note that changing the value of a control at runtime is a little odd. They are intended to be static. Is there a specific reason you need to do this?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the value so that when another action is performed, it checks to see which button is pressed so that can do something based on which button is pressed. Kind of like a big giant radio selection. I had thought of using radio buttons and restyling, but I felt it would take me as long, if not longer that way.

Comment: In that case it would be much simpler to add a class to the active button, and then find the button by that class when the other action occurs.

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean Rory?

Comment: Sure, I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments:

> I want to change the value so that when another action is performed, it checks to see which button is pressed so that can do something based on which button is pressed. Kind of like a big giant radio selection.

In this case it would be simpler to add a different class to the button instead of changing its `value`, which is intended to be static. When the later action occurs you can find the active button by placing the class in a selector, something like this:

```js
$(".stuck").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).toggleClass('unstuck');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.stuck').not(this).removeClass('active');
});

$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($('button.active').prop('id') || 'Nothing selected');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%"><button class="stuck unstuck" name="doR1" id="doR1">AP Enquiry</button></td>
    <td width="10%"><button class="stuck unstuck" name="doR2" id="doR2">HM Enquiry</button></td>
    <td width="10%"><button class="stuck unstuck" name="doR3" id="doR3">Ac/Rj Pgm</button></td>
    <td width="10%"><button class="stuck unstuck" name="doR4" id="doR4">Property Enq</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a href="#">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory :).  I'm going to have a play with that and see if it works for me, because the bit that I haven't included is that the program is 2 different languages bound together during compile time. RPGLE and html. the Rpg program "sees" nothing that goes on in the scripting language and only understands the html. But I think I can get it to work for me. I hope so anyway, as your coding is so much simpler than what I was attempting (and very elegant too I might add). I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: That work for me with a little bit of modification Rory. I just used a hidden element to collect the change, the rpg was then able to pick up the hidden element. Perfect!! You're the man in my books. Thank you not only for answering my question, but for not making it really hard work :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)